# Itunes won't display total number of songs when I'm in my music playlist

Tags: itunes

Itunes used to display my total number of songs/hours/days when I was in the MUSIC playlist. It displays this info for all of my playlist, just not in MUSIC. I know how to use control +/ to get the info to appear, just can't figure out why it won't show the info for all of my 15,000 songs...

Comment: Try toggling the "Show/Hide Status Bar" item in iTune's View Menu. It *should* toggle that info for all media types, but perhaps it glitched once and needs a little prod to work correctly again.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, still doesn't work, so odd...

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for an answer, go to Playlists, then on the right side it will have a drop down menu that says Songs, if you choose Artists instead, it will show you how many songs you have on the left side

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the max screen is too large, you might need to

1. On the Start screen, press and hold the tile you want to resize. (If you’re using a mouse, right-click the tile.)
2. Tap or click Resize.
3. Choose the size you want.